# Javascript to select multiple files from multiple folders

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing one html page, in which I want the user to select multiple files from multiple folders.
Also, I am using bootstrap 3
I didn't find any documentation in bootstrap to do so :

```
<div class="form1">
  <label for="input-folder-3">Select folders</label>
  <div class="file-loading">
  <input id="input-folder-3" name="input-folder-3[]" type="file" multiple><br/>
  <input class="mt-3" type="submit" value="Ok" id="submit">
</div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#input-folder-3").fileinput({
      uploadUrl: "/file-upload-batch/2",
      hideThumbnailContent: true // hide image, pdf, text or other content in the thumbnail 
       preview
     });
 });
</script>
```

I have tried this, but this is not working

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific about your request? What do you want to depict and what should be the goal of the exercise?

Comment: The goal of the exrecise is, when the user is clicking on the choose files button, it should allow them to select multiple files from multiple folders.

Comment: @PriyaChauhan That's an option that I don't think many file uploaders support. Not sure, but most probably not even windows supports it for file selection. Usually, if you want to select multiple files from different folders, you press choose files as many times as you change the folder you select the files from